# Magento 2 - Where Knockout js variable are defined?

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs, checkout-summary

In Magento 2 I don't understand how knockout js templates work.

In this file : `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/item/details.phtml`

```
<div class="product-item-inner">
    <div class="product-item-name-block">
        <strong class="product-item-name" data-bind="html: $parent.name"></strong>
        <div class="details-qty">
            <span class="label"><!-- ko i18n: 'Qty' --><!-- /ko --></span>
            <span class="value" data-bind="text: $parent.qty"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('after_details') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

I need to know where `html: $parent.name` and `text: $parent.qty` are defined, in order to change these values.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

We need to create Plugin to do so
create a < vender >/< module >/etc/di.xml file

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider">
        <plugin name="AddAttPlug" type="Mycar\Checkout\Plugin\ConfigProviderPlugin" />
    </type>
```

< vender >/< module >/Plugin/ConfigProviderPlugin.php

```
public function afterGetConfig(\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject, array $result) {
    $_items = [];
    $quoteId = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getId();
    if ($quoteId) {
        $itemOptionCount = count($result['totalsData']['items']);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $itemOptionCount; $i++) {           
                $result['totalsData']['items'][$i]['name'] = 'Test name';
                $result['totalsData']['items'][$i]['qty'] = 2;
                $_items[$i] = $result['totalsData']['items'][$i];
        }
        $result['totalsData']['items'] = $_items;
        json_encode($result);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Ok I understand, but how to access $parent.name variable and change value in php ?

Comment: @Fbr please check the updated code

Comment: Ok thanks, it work on checkout step "delivery" but it doesn't work in next step "payment". Is it managed in 2 different ways ?

Comment: @Fbr this was only for delivery step, need to do the same for the payment step too.

Comment: Yes I understand, but how to do it ? Where is code for payment step ?